# ignore NuGet package from .netstandard ProjectReference

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, .net-standard

i have the following project structure in a `Xamarin` project.
[image: project structure]

a `.netstandard` library contains `NuGet` package `X` which should also be available in project `B` and `C` which reference `A` via `ProjectReference` in the `.csproj`.

In Project `D` i would ignore or exclude the `NuGet` package coming from the `.netstandard` `A` because i have my own implementation for this platform (`custom X`). How would one set up a scenario like this is the project settings?

**EDIT: more info**

`Package X` is a multitargeted NuGet package which has support for the platform of `B` and `C` but on `D` I want to reference my own code.

Comment: ... i have my own implementation for this platform .... So "A" would be a reference (proxy) library and thus "custom X" which would not be a .netstandard library due to platform specific implementation and would be added to the platform specific project (not shown in your diagram) to supply "D" with the platform related calls. B and C would reference your non-platform .NetStd implementation but also in the platform specific project  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies

Comment: i still have to keep a reference to the netstandard project (A) in the platform specific project (D). If i just add the custom NuGet to D i get the following error: "An assembly with the same simple name 'MyLib' has already been imported. Try removing one of the references or sign them to enable side-by-side"

Comment: @nor0x If you do not want to remove the redundant reference, you could try to rename one of the references, or provide a strong name for them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1704

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks for the reply. If I set a strong name for the redundant reference then I get "The type ... exists in both ... and ...
I need a solution to how I can reference the netstandard project but not the NuGet that it references

Comment: @nor0x Strong-naming an assembly creates a unique identity for the assembly, and can prevent assembly conflicts. How do you set it? You could refer to the link below about how to sign an assembly with a strong name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/sign-strong-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using `ItemGroup` conditions in my `.csproj` files to include / exclude packages based on the `TargetFramework`. Works fine for this usecase

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('A')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="package-for-A-and-B Version="1.2.3">
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('B')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="package-for-A-and-B Version="1.2.3">
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('D')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="package-for-D Version="1.2.3">
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```